# ActiveSheet.Delete not showing prompt (when it should)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

Good evening, I have an add-in with a very simple Sub procedure to delete the active sheet. For ease of use, I have bound the Sub to a key combination via Application.OnKey in the add-in's Workbook_Open call.

See below for the code. Despite the use of Application.DisplayAlerts = True, the actual code execution will delete the sheet **without** a prompt. However, because this is a keybind, I want to force the prompt to avoid accidental deletion.

What's going on?

```
Public Sub DeleteActiveSheet()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    If ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count = 1 Then
        MsgBox "You cannot delete the only sheet in a workbook."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ActiveSheet.Delete

End Sub
```

Edit: I should mention that stepping through the code produces the expected behavior and displays the prompt in all tests done so far. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out: prompting for sheet deletion only triggers a prompt if there is any data in the sheet.

In most of my tests, where I'd add a sheet and then attempted to delete it immediately afterward, wouldn't trigger the prompt even when I was expecting it.

Having any data on the sheet and then activating the keybind results in a prompt as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried your code and the prompt appears. This might be an issue with your settings. 
[image]

I should mention that I bound it to ctrl+g and executed the code that way.

Comment: I'll try remapping the key combination, but what settings could be causing this? I'm not familiar with anything that would suppress the prompts within Excel, as I would have pounced on that a long time ago!

Comment: I remapped to Ctrl-g, as well as Ctrl-`, and still had the same non-prompt behavior.

Comment: I don't believe there is a setting for excel to disable all alerts. It is enabled by default and re-enables when your code finishes. Does your message box appear when there is only 1 sheet?

Comment: oh, I didn't notice that you are binding the key in the workbook_open event. It's possible that that is causing the issue. There is a built-in key binding option in the Developer Tab -> macros -> options.